# What property of gray code makes it minimum error code?

Tags: digital-logic

Other way round, If I am building a new code how should I make it minimum error code?

Comment: What do you mean by "minimum error code"? I've never heard that phrase before, and I did a Google search for it in order to try to find out what it means, but I couldn't find any plausible meanings of it.

Comment: what code are you building? ... you may be misunderstanding how gray code is used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best I can tell, this is a “concept” that someone came up with in a textbook and then it spread like wildfire. It’s not a very useful concept since “minimum error code” is used as a synonym for Gray code. It has no other meanings and just muddies the water. I’m 99% sure that your teacher just regurgitates this nonsense without pausing to think about it.

There is really nothing "minimum error" about the Gray code though. Any code can have the same property with many bits changing at once. The property is that from any state there are just two transitions valid to other states, and the longer the code word, the more redundancy there is. But this property does not depend on only one bit changing at a time (!).

The applications for Gray code have not much to do with "errors", but in making the transition  detection easier to implement in systems where each bit of the code word may update at a slightly different time, so the receiving system could end up recognizing a transitional code word that is not intentional. That is a very nice implementation property in such systems, but from any fundamental theoretic view of data coding, it's not of big importance.

Answer (score 2):

With gray code because only one bit changes at each step of code the worst result you can get from a read race-condtition  (where the read happens at the same time as the data is changing) is off by one.

You can make shorter gray codes by skipping sections of a gray code,  for example if you want a 360 count gray code start with a 512 count code then skip a 128 count secton  where the two ends only differ by a single bit then similar 16 and 8 count sections leaving you with a 360 count gray code. All gray codes have an even number of counts.

Answer (score 0):

As with other codes you could send additional bits (or data words), that when summed in a certain way along with the original data results in a CRC like number (or checksum). If the receiver detects that the CRC value is not correct it asks the transmitter to resend the data. That type of error checking format is fairly standard in modern digital communications.

Even a single bit can be used as a simple parity check, (an odd or even count of similar bits). This method was very common in some older serial communication formats.

The old style Gray code only changes 1 bit of a data word at any incrementing or decrementing step, so if there is more than a one bit change the receiving system easily knows there was an error. This can be used in systems such as digital encoders that count up or down.

For even more info you can read the [wiki article on Grey Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code).